# Ruby treats method with uppercase name differently

Tags: ruby

Here's a simple example

```
class Foo
  def self.lowercase
    puts "lowercase"
  end

  def self.Uppercase
    puts "uppercase method"
  end
end

Foo::lowercase
Foo::Uppercase
```

This outputs:

```
lowercase
foo.rb:12:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Foo::Uppercase (NameError)
```

Why doesn't Ruby find the `Uppercase` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't Ruby find the `Uppercase` method?

Because it thinks it's a constant. `::` is the constant resolution operator. The fact that it also works for message sends is not really useful outside of obfuscated programming contests.

If you want to treat it as a message send, you have to make clear to Ruby that you mean a message send, by either passing an empty argument list or using standard message sending syntax:

```
Foo::Uppercase()
Foo.Uppercase
```

How else would you be able to access a constant named `Uppercase` namespaced within `Foo`?

Note that this is similar to local variables:

```
def foo; 'method' end

foo #=> 'method'

foo = 'variable'

foo #=> 'variable'

foo() #=> 'method'

self.foo #=> 'method'
```

Comment: "The fact that it also works for message sends is not really useful outside of obfuscated programming contests." Or maybe misguided attempts at interviewing candidates and finding Ruby "experts". Either way, lol.

Comment: Your mentioning of the similarity with local variable may be confusing. Constants and local variables are different, as stated in my question linked. And your answer there is clearer on that.